# JavaMailSender setup Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-batch

I'm having trouble configuring a `JavaMailSender` to create and send an email. My Spring Batch job executes the `sendEmailStep` but never creates the email message

Here are the pieces I have.

**InstanceTestBatchConfiguration.java**

In this Config I've setup a `sendEmailStep` that calls a tasklet

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class InstanceTestBatchConfiguration {

    // tag::jobstep[]
    @Bean(name = "mccINSTANCETESTjob")
    public Job mccOrz004job(JobBuilderFactory jobFactory, //
            @Qualifier("instanceTestSetupStep") Step orz004SetupStep, //
            @Qualifier("callM204Step") Step callM204Step, //
            @Qualifier("sendEmailStep") Step sendEmailStep, //
            @Autowired SingleInstanceListener listener) { //
        return jobFactory.get("mccINSTANCETESTjob") //
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()) //
                .start(orz004SetupStep) //
                .next(sendEmailStep) //
                .next(callM204Step) //
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "instanceTestSetupStep")
    public Step instanceTestSetupStep(StepBuilderFactory stepFactory, InstanceTestSetupTasklet task) {
        return stepFactory.get("instanceTestSetupStep") //
                .tasklet(task) //
                .allowStartIfComplete(true).build();
    }
    // end::jobstep[]
}
```

**SendEmailTasklet.java** Here I have setup an example email to be sent

```
@Component
public class SendEmailTasklet implements Tasklet {

    final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SendEmailTasklet.class);

    @Autowired
    public JavaMailSender emailSender;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo("exampleemail@google.com");
        message.setSubject("Hello world");
        message.setText("This is a test email");
        emailSender.send(message);

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

}
```

**application.properties** I have the following fields set, but omitting them for the question

```
spring.mail.host=xxx
spring.mail.port=xxx
#spring.mail.username=xxxx@xxx.com
#spring.mail.password=xxxx
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it's working. I had setup a mail service like MailHog to handle ingoing and outgoing emails and it wasn't configured to release emails